# documentation links for extending google maps JS v3 Marker class

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for documentation links on how to extend google maps classes such as google.maps.Marker. I did find a very helpful link at http://www.googlemapsbook.com/2007/01/22/extending-gmarker/. However that is for api v2 and I am using api V3. I also looked at google's documentation to extend OverlayTypes here (http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#CustomOverlays) however, that does not apply to Marker which is an MvcObject. I also read and understood that for most practical requirements, we wont need to extend the Marker class. It has a very useful interface with which you can do almost everything you need. However, my app is now becoming complex and I would love to encapsulate some of my custom features in a custom marker class that extends Google's marker. Is that even possible or am I dreaming?

Thank you folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`google.maps.Marker` is an object.
You don't need a special interface to extend objects, you may extend the prototype of google.maps.Marker.

Sample:

```
  //applies a onclick-listener to a marker where the marker will be removed
  google.maps.Marker.prototype.removeOnClick=function()
                  {
                    google.maps.event.clearListeners(this,'click');
                    google.maps.event.addListener(this, 'click', 
                            function() {
                                          alert('bye');
                                          this.setMap(null);
                                       });
                  };
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/KgTF5/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/KgTF5/)

Comment: thank you. i am not sure i elaborated my question correctly. In any case, I ended up using open layers and openstreetmap for my work. I get more flexibility and also more trouble, but it works out better than google maps for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I agree the statements : ' You don't need a special interface to extend objects '
If you want to add some properties into 'google.maps.Marker' for your case , the method:

```
marker.set("property", New_Value);
```

could be helpful. Also you can use :

```
marker.get("propertu");
```

to get target value.